# Handle Password Expiry in SSIS Web services

Tags: web-services, ssis

I have a SSIS integration package in which I am accessing my client system using Web Services for importing the data from the client system to my sql server.

The entire component is working fine however I have an issue with the web services part. The Password provided for the web service authentication expires every 120 days. Due to this issue, I am not able to have a fully automated system as every 120 days I am manually updating the password for the web service.

Is there any way to handle this? Due to client confidentiality I am not supposed to provide the information related to my web services.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where do you store your password now? In an environment, in a config or hard coded? Do you reset the pwd or do they send you one? Do you have an API to reset the password?

Comment: The password is hard coded in the http connection manager component and we are manually changing the password in the web services. The password can be kept in a variable but for every 120 days i have to update the variable with the new password right?

Comment: You can populate variables at run time with configs (sql 2008 and before) or parameters (sql 2012 onwards). Why don't you share the version of SSIS. I still don't understand how you are resetting the password (not in the package but in the web service that you call). Do you have to go to a web site to reset your password? That's the other piece of this automation.

Comment: Yes. I will be going to an web page to reset the password. Then will take the new password and put it in the variable.

Comment: So if you are running SSIS 2008 or prior (I still don't know) then you use configs. Otherwise you use environments and parameters